# Pytorch autograd.grad how to write the parameters for multiple outputs?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

In the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html?highlight=autograd%20grad#torch.autograd.grad) of `torch.autograd.grad`, it is stated that, for parameters,

> parameters:
>
> outputs (sequence of Tensor) – outputs of the differentiated function.
>
> inputs (sequence of Tensor) – Inputs w.r.t.
>   which the gradient will be returned (and not accumulated into .grad).

I try the following:

```
a = torch.rand(2, requires_grad=True)
b = torch.rand(2, requires_grad=True)
c = a+b
d = a-b

torch.autograd.grad([c, d], [a, b]) #ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
torch.autograd.grad(torch.tensor([c, d]), torch.tensor([a, b])) #RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs
```

I would like to get gradients of a list of tensors w.r.t another list of tensors. What is the correct way to feed the parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [torch.autograd.grad](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.grad) mentioned, `torch.autograd.grad` computes and returns the sum of gradients of outputs w.r.t. the inputs. Since your `c` and `d` are not scalar values, `grad_outputs` are required.

```py
import torch

a = torch.rand(2,requires_grad=True)
b = torch.rand(2, requires_grad=True)

a
# tensor([0.2308, 0.2388], requires_grad=True)

b
# tensor([0.6314, 0.7867], requires_grad=True)

c = a*a + b*b
d = 2*a+4*b

torch.autograd.grad([c,d], inputs=[a,b], grad_outputs=[torch.Tensor([1.,1.]), torch.Tensor([1.,1.])])
# (tensor([2.4616, 2.4776]), tensor([5.2628, 5.5734]))
```

Explanation:
`dc/da = 2*a = [0.2308*2, 0.2388*2]`
`dd/da = [2.,2.]`
So the first output is `dc/da*grad_outputs[0]+dd/da*grad_outputs[1] = [2.4616, 2.4776]`. Same calculation for the second output.

If you just want to get the gradient of `c` and `d` w.r.t. the inputs, probably you can do this:

```py
a = torch.rand(2,requires_grad=True)
b = torch.rand(2, requires_grad=True)

a
# tensor([0.9566, 0.6066], requires_grad=True)
b
# tensor([0.5248, 0.4833], requires_grad=True)

c = a*a + b*b
d = 2*a+4*b

[torch.autograd.grad(t, inputs=[a,b], grad_outputs=[torch.Tensor([1.,1.])]) for t in [c,d]]
# [(tensor([1.9133, 1.2132]), tensor([1.0496, 0.9666])),
# (tensor([2., 2.]), tensor([4., 4.]))]
```

Comment: This is the only example I can find for multi-variables of `autograd.grad`. However, I think the first output is computed by `(dc/da)*grad_outputs[0] +(dd/da)*grad_outputs[1] = [2.4616, 2.4776]`.

Comment: thanks, I implemented this in my multioutput neural network which requires custom autograds in the loss function.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go
In the example you gave:

```
a = torch.rand(2, requires_grad=True)
b = torch.rand(2, requires_grad=True)
loss = a + b
```

As the loss is a vector with 2 elements, you can't perform the autograd operation at once.

typically,

```
loss = torch.sum(a + b)
torch.autograd.grad([loss], [a, b])
```

This would return the correct value of gradient for the loss tensor which contains one element.
You can pass mutiple scalar tensors to outputs argument of the `torch.autograd.grad` method

Comment: So the outputs can only be scalar or list of scalar? Can't we get derivatives of vector by vector (Hessian matrix)?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I could find out. Even in typical neural net, we always have the loss summed or averaged over all the mini batch samples before back propagating.